# How to get time in specific format - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, date, datetime

I need to write a simple script of in bash. How do i get the current time in Linux in the specific format of
    HH:MM am or pm, eg 05:30 a.m.

Answer (score 0):

Use date formatter

```
$date +  "%I:%M %P"
```

Comment: but how to get the H to be in 12 hour time? also is it possible to make specifically "a.m." or "p.m."

Comment: Better use `%I` instead of `%H` to go with an am/pm. "19:28 pm" looks weird.

Comment: Add the following to the end for a.m. and p.m.   | sed -e 's/am/a.m./' -e 's/pm/p.m./'